# Find resources of Class Library from Main Project

Tags: c#, .net, clickonce, visual-studio-2019

**The Problem**

My solution is made up of a handful of projects. The main one for the UI we'll call Assistant, and the backend we'll call AssistantLib.

Here is the structure:

[image]

In AssistantLib I have included PDFs as resources in a Resources folder with a `Build Action` of **Content** and `Copy to Output Directory` as **Copy Always**. I am able to locate them when debugging by using a combo of these:

```
    private string GetArtifactPath(string artifactName)
    {
        return Path.Combine(GetResourcePath(), artifactName);
    }

    public static string GetResourcePath()
    {
        return Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Resources");
    }
```

This works. Once I return the string from GetArtifactPath, I open the File with a `Process` object and `AcroRd32.exe`.

Note that I need to reference these files by their file paths. They're not simple txts to read or stream. I also need to be able to open them with certain flag provided by `AcroRd32.exe`. That means **I must have the file path**.

The problem I'm having as that once I publish the ClickOnce app, I receive an error that the file couldn't be found:

```
Error: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\EL-C\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\3JCPDD49.7G5\9122AMZE.NZL\azte..tion_edea8654ffceff97_0001.0000_447ed0da08290357\Resources\Guidelines\3.2'.. Stacktrace:    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
```

And of course, when I go to that location, the resources aren't there.

**What I've Tried**

- I've changed the `Build Action` to Embedded Resource & None - same result
- I've changed the `Copy Output Directory` to Do Not Copy
- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30006530/cant-find-embedded-resource-using-getmanifestresourcestream) doesn't apply because I can't stream these resources, they're not simple text files. I'm also not trying to read them, I'm trying to open them.
- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964942/how-to-access-resource-file-in-c) also doesn't apply because referencing `MyNamespace.Properties.Resources.My_Zip_File;` doesn't work in my situation. I don't know the name of the resource ahead of time.

**Update**

I am looking into post-build events. In doing so, I found that these resources are **already** in the output directory following a build:

[image]

But for some reason they don't show up when I publish:

[image]

**Update 2**

To illustrate how the folder structure affects this, here are before and afters.

When a Resource is in `AssistantLib` (e.g. EVMSBP), this is the structure:

[image: Resource in Lib]

And here is what the ClickOnce publish folder looks like after installing with the resource in `AssistantLib`:

[image: Missing]

Alternatively, when a Resource is in `Assistant` (again EVMSBP), this is the structure:

[image: Resource in Assistant]

And here's what the ClickOnce publish folder looks like after installing with the resource in `Assistant`:

[image: Not Missing]

From what I can tell, the Resource MUST be a part of the Startup project. That sounds like insanity?

What am I missing?

Comment: Don't use `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`. You don't know what  Directory will be the *current*. Depending on the type of project, you can use `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`, `Application.StartupPath`, `AppContext.BaseDirectory`, `Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)` etc. (`Environment.CurrentDirectory` is not good either)

Comment: Hey User, I understand that all your pdfs get copied to output dir on build action right ?

Comment: @Clint - I've played with a few settings. In the current iteration they do. Maybe I don't fully understand where the output dir is?

Comment: the same directory where your exe is

Comment: Yeah, see my edit. On Build, they're being placed there; not on Publish, which is incredibly frustrating.

Comment: hey @user, have sent a chat invite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With more details from the edit, this is how I replicated it

- In ***AssistLib*** project

  - Files in Resources with **`Build Action`** as **`Embedded Resources`**.
  - `Output Type:` *`Class Library`* *(AssistLib.dll)*
  - See [Solution Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3DIh.png)

- In ***AzTech*** Main Project

  - I referenced the **`AssistLib.dll`**
  - Check if the *resource* (pdf) that I want to load exists in AssistLib.dll
  - Loads the resource
  - Launches the PDF
  - So far so good
  - I Published the App and installed
  - I launched the App from the Icon on the Start Menu
  - Which Launch the PDF that was embedded as resource in the DLL

**AzTech.cs**

```
var nameOfTheFile = "test.pdf";
ResourceManager.GetResourceInfo(nameOfTheFile);
if (ResourceManager.resourceExists == false)
{ Console.WriteLine("Specified PDF file not found"); return; }

Console.WriteLine("Resouce found in DLL");
ResourceManager.LoadResource(nameOfTheFile);//Will load the pdf in your main project

Process.Start(nameOfTheFile);
```

```
 class ResourceManager
 {
        public static bool resourceExists { get; set; } = false;
        private static Stream resourceStream { get; set; }
        public static void GetResourceInfo(string fileNameWithExtension)
        {
            const string pathToResource = "AssistantLib.Resources.Guidelines";

            var assembly = Assembly.Load("AssistantLib");
            //var names = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();
            var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream($"{pathToResource}.{fileNameWithExtension}");
            if (stream == null)
                return;

            resourceExists = true;

            resourceStream = stream;

        }

        public static void LoadResource(string newFileNameWithExtension)
        {
            if(File.Exists(newFileNameWithExtension))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("File already exists");
                return;
            }
            using (Stream s = File.Create(newFileNameWithExtension))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Loading file");
                resourceStream.CopyTo(s);
            }
        }
 }
```

Comment: Hey @Clint, appreciate the post. I don't believe paths are causing the issue. In the solution structure you posted, the resource is in the Startup project. The problem I'm facing is that when the resource is in another project in the solution, `AssistantLib` in this case, the resource doesn't ship once published and installed. See my second update to see comparison images.

Comment: @user, so basically you want to reference AssistantLib which contains the resource from your main AssistantProject. Which means AssistantLib project results in a DLL which you would consume from MainProject, correct ? and then you would publish the main project

Comment: hey, this worked. Making them Embedded Resources, `Assembly.Load` & `assembly.ManifestResourceStream` were the key. Appreciate the help.

Comment: One question I have - what's the best way to manage Resources in /Resources/Guidelines AND /Resources. Or is that bad practice?

Comment: What do you mean by manage, what is the intent ? you do not want to bulk up your resource by embedding too many things than what is necessary. Another way to to embed is to navigate to Visual Studio > Project > Properties > Resource . You can also add resources that way.

Comment: Should have been clearer - I mean organize. The library is going to contain a series of documents as resources. That's part of what it's designed for because the UI is for searching them.

Comment: ahh okie, I do not have a particular remedy for that :), I would do it, just as we organize anything else group the related ones into a folder and that pointing to the parent one

Comment: I figured as much. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

i was facing same problem when i was building the project on exe format using the visual studio setup i simple add pdf file in project build output directory . you have to copy your pdf folder in **bin** or **release** folder and use ~ root directory to get file